# How to animate a glowing surface with radial color gradient that fades out after short while? Bioluminescence / "Avatar Effect"?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation

how do I animate glowing foot prints that fade out after a few seconds? I created this animation of a person walking up a set of stairs and would like to add the mensioned effect, like in James Cameron's Avatar.

[image]

Basically I was thinking about adding a light emitting surface around the foot that sort of begins to glow violette in its center when the foot touches it and then fades out to its edges with a darker blue after the foot left. 
I would be willing to animate it frame by frame to avoid anything like dynamic paint.

Anyone an idea? Thank you!

Comment: What about using empties hooked to the feet. The floor material uses a Mix Shader to activate Emission with a Factor based on a Gradient mapped to an Object UV, specifically the Empty. The glow would predict the foot fall but also drift and fade as the foot steps away.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I struggle with actually setting the nodes up due to lack of knowledge. Could you post a picture of a simple setup of what you try to explain? Especially as I don't quite understand what you mean by mapping something to an empty. Cheers.